# Azure DevOps Pipeline not caching Python dependencies

Tags: python, docker, caching, azure-devops

I'm trying to create an Azure DevOps pipeline that will build a Docker image and cache it. I partially managed to succeed, in the logs of the Docker build I can see that the cache is being used:

```
Step 1/21 : FROM python:3.10.11-slim-buster
 ---> 68a2f83bcffa
Step 2/21 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 001762e23706
Step 3/21 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cbbac992a155
```

However I see that regardless of my changes in the repository the "RUN" lines are not cached:

```
Step 4/21 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in aad240f867bc
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=65.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (65.5.1)
Collecting pandas==1.5.3
  Downloading pandas-1.5.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.1/12.1 MB 50.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
.
.
.
```

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.11-slim-buster

# specify workdir
WORKDIR /

# copy files
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY /src /src
COPY pyproject.toml setup.cfg setup.py MANIFEST.in /
COPY /test /test

# specifying environmental variable that states on which environment container is running
ARG ENV
ENV ENV=$ENV

# install project
RUN pip install .
```

What I want to achieve is that if there are **no changes** in the *requirements.txt* file the first "RUN" command would be restored from cache (I guess that's how it works, right?), so the build doesn't waste time installing dependencies all over again.

Here's part of my azure-pipeline.yaml:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
  - job: 'Docker'
    steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: '"$(env)"'

      - task: JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension.artifactory-tools-installer-task.ArtifactoryToolsInstaller@1
        displayName: 'Artifactory Tools Installer (CLI)'
        inputs:
          artifactoryService: $(jfrogCredentials)
          cliInstallationRepo: 'jfrog-cli'

      - task: Cache@2
        displayName: Cache task
        inputs:
          key: 'docker | "$(Agent.OS)" | cache'
          path: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker
          cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED   

      - script: |
          docker load -i $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker/cache.tar
        displayName: Docker restore
        condition: and(not(canceled()), eq(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true'))

      - task: Docker@2
        name: BuildDockerImage
        displayName: Build docker image for JFrog
        inputs:
          repository: $(jfrogRepositoryName)
          command: 'build'
          Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
          tags: $(tag)
          arguments:
            '--build-arg accountID=$(accountID) --cache-from=$(jfrogRepositoryName):$(tag)'
      
      - script: |
          mkdir -p $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker
          docker save -o $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker/cache.tar $(jfrogRepositoryName):$(tag)
        displayName: Docker save
        condition: and(not(canceled()), not(failed()), ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'true'))

      - task: JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension.artifactory-docker.ArtifactoryDocker@1
        displayName: 'Artifactory Docker push'
        inputs:
          artifactoryService: $(jfrogCredentials)
          targetRepo: $(jfrogTargetRepo)
          imageName: $(jfrogRepositoryName)

      - task: CmdLine@2
        displayName: 'Rename JFrog image to upload to AWS'
        inputs:
          script: 'docker image tag $(jfrogRepositoryName):$(tag) $(awsRepositoryName):$(tag)' 

      - task: ECRPushImage@1
        condition: always()
        inputs:
          awsCredentials: $(awsCredentials)
          regionName: $(awsRegion)
          sourceImageName: $(awsRepositoryName)
          repositoryName: $(awsRepositoryName)
          autoCreateRepository: true
          forceDockerNamingConventions: true
```

I based my code on the things I found on the internet (for example from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops), but it seems like there is little information on how to do it properly. If you could tell me what I'm doing wrong or where to look for an answer, I'd appreciate.